# How to solve on press up on expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Can i catch on press up event? For exam: I press TouchableOpacity and my action trigger. But i want to catch after press. How cani solve it?

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert("Pressed")} onAnyAction={() => alert("Press lefted")}>
   <Text> Button </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: U want to do something after your alert appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found. onPressIn and onPressOut.